# Display a form field i.e., a choice field of form in the template django

Tags: django, forms, templates

I've have forms.py file in that i have a choice field which i've to display it in the template.html

forms.py

```
 Choices = [('Yelp',)]
 class UtilitiesForm(forms.Form):
     api_select = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), 
                  choices=Choices)
     text_url = forms.CharField()
```

template.html

```
{% block body_content %}

  <form action="/utilities/fetch-data/" method="post" id="utitliy__form">
     <div class="form-row">
         <label>Select an API</label>
           {{ form.api_select }}
     </div>
  </form>
 {% endblock body_content %}
```

i'm getting Value error can you guys help me how to write the choice field in template.html

Comment: Can you please post the *full* traceback?

Comment: Furthermore I do not completely understand why you use a `MultipleChoiceField` with a `Select` widget: the `Select` widget only allows to select *one* choice, whereas `MulitpleChoiceField`s are aimed to select, well, multiple options (zero, one or more).

Answer (score 1):

You need not to do anything with choice field in forms.py you can directly use it in your template.
*template*

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="order_no">Order No.:</label>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{Order}}" name="order_no" readonly><br>
        <label for="isbn">ISBN No.:</label>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{ISBN}}" name="isbn" readonly><br>
        <label for="rate">Rate:</label>{{forms.rate}}(Rate us 10 is the Highest and 1 is the lowest)<br><br>
        <label for="comment">Comments</label>{{forms.comment}}<br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

*Models.py*

```
RATING=( (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (8,8), (9,9), (10,10) )
class returnbook(models.Model):
    order_no=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    isbn=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    rate=models.IntegerField(choices=RATING,default='1')
    comment=models.TextField(max_length=20000,blank=True)
    user=models.CharField(max_length=50) 

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('order_no', 'isbn')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**`choices`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) should be:

> Either an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of **2-tuples** to use as
>   choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable.
>   This argument accepts the same formats as the choices argument to a
>   model field. See the model field reference documentation on choices
>   for more details. If the argument is a callable, it is evaluated each
>   time the field’s form is initialized. Defaults to an empty list.

Here you provide it an iterable of 1-tuples. The tuple specify the value, and the textual representation, for example:

```
API_SELECT_CHOICES = [('yelp', 'Yelp')]

class UtilitiesForm(forms.Form):
    api_select = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=API_SELECT_CHOICES
    )
    text_url = forms.CharField()
```

It is also strange that you used a `MultipleChoiceField` with a `Select` widget. Normally a `Select` widget is used to select *exactly* one element, whereas a `SelectMultiple` widget is used to select *zero*, *one*, or *more* elements. So I here changed the field to `ChoiceField`. A `ChoiceField` with a `Select` widget makes sense, and a `MultipleChoiceField` with a `SelectMultiple` makes sense, but the other combinations do not make much sense.

Comment: I've used `ChoiceField` aslo but i'm getting error ,                        need more than 1 value to unpack
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/utilities/fetch-data/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
need more than 1 value to unpack
Exception Location: /Users/apple/move-easy/move-easy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in render_options, line 567
Python Executable: /Users/apple/move-easy/move-easy/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.13

Comment: @krishnakrish: did you cange the `choices`? Please post the *full* error.

Comment: @krishnakrish: I have the impression you did *not* change the `choices` to `[('yelp', 'Yelp')]`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the choice in form

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, _("Unread")),(2, _("Read"))),default=1)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'status']
```

**in views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm # Add form which is written in your forms.py
def index(request):
    context = {}
    form = UserForm() #Initiate 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**index.html** you will get choice in html

```
<form action="{% url 'about' %}" method="POST" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
</form>
```

for more details please refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices)