# Django:Choices and Foreign fIelds not being rendered on form

Tags: python, html, django, forms, render

inputs involving foreign keys,booleans,and choices are not being rendered on my form.please help

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Document

class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    summary_text = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def createDoc(request):

    form = DocumentForm()

    context= {"form":form}
    return render(request,'main/document_form.html',context)
```

document_form.html

```
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token%}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" value="SUMBIT">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099993/11594778

Comment: My major concern is on parent models.How do i go about that?